# c++ memory in array of class objects

Tags: c++, class, memory, layout, member

I have a class like this:

```
class Object {
public: 
    unsigned char data[8];
    // other variables
    // functions etc...
 };
```

The question is - are the object members all stored in the same place in memory relative to the object? So if I have an array: Object array[3], given a char pointer
`char* data_ptr = array[0].data`, will
`data_ptr + (sizeof(Object))` then always point to array[1].data?

(I've read a couple of Q/As about how there might be padding inbetween data members of classes and structs - but I don't think they answer my question.)

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof Object` already includes all internal padding of the class `Object`. including any padding at its end. Arrays don't allow any additional padding. Therefore it is true that `data_ptr + sizeof Object` will have the address of `array[1].data`.

*However* I'm not sure if this is actually allowed. That is, the compiler *might* be allowed to assume that you never add a value larger than 8 (the size of the member array `data`) to `array[0].data`, and therefore it might apply optimizations that fail if you violate the rules. That is, your code might actually exhibit undefined behavior (which is the standard term for "the compiler is allowed to do anything in this case").

*However* since you are using a pointer to `char`, for which there are more permissive rules (you can do many things with `char*` which you could not do with general types), it may be that it's actually defined behaviour anyway.

Comment: while `char*` can be good for generic data, isn't `unsigned char*` or `uint8_t` the method of choice for raw byte access?

Comment: It is true that for accessing raw bytes, `unsigned char+` or `uint8_t` is the better choice (because on non 2's complement machines, there are two representations of zero). However the more permissive rules also apply for `char`. And in this special case, no raw byte access happens; the array the pointer ultimately points to is an array of `char` again.

Comment: I don't understand your second paragraph (why 8?) (sorry - I'm new to c++!).
It seems to work for me at the moment (using it to copy unsigned char values from one array to another) but I obviously want to make sure problems won't surface in the future!

Comment: @user1483596: `8` because you've defined the member `data` as `char data[8]`. That is, adding 8 to `array[0].data` gives you the one-past-end pointer of that member array, which is of course allowed. Adding anything larger means you leave the array, which might be undefined behaviour (which means the compiler is allowed to do whatever it wants in that case, and therefore optimizations may go wrong if you do it).

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you can translate "undefined behaviour" as "don't do it."

Answer (score 2):

If the aim of your question is to understand how things are in memory, then it is acceptable.

But if you want **to do that for real**: What you want to do **is actually criminal** against all your colleagues.

The proper way to go through collection in C++ is not to use an array, but an **std::vector**, or another std collection *if it is really needed*. We shouuld no longer use C arithmetics, but access the items of the vector collection through an iterator. That's the reason of the C++ standard library :-)

Comment: I'll investigate iterators - haven't used them before (I'm new to c++). The reason I went for this pointer method is because I need to copy the elements of data from thousands of objects to another array, which I then draw using opengl.

Comment: you can also instanciate an std::vector on a C array: I will post the code below my answer just for your information to show you how to do. I do advise you to learn how to use the std library. Slowly / at your pace it's ok, welcome to c++ ;-)

Comment: too bad, I have spoken too early... although it's easy to have a standard c-array from a std::vector (pointing on it's first element, and considering it's size), on the contrary I have not found a way to have a new std::vector pointing on an already existing array ( which is what you are supplied with opengl as I understand): impossible to do so without copying the content of the array, which is probably ineficient for big arrays as you can have with images.

Comment: No problem - I'll investigate myself. I already have an Array class as a wrapper round a pure array, I'll see how easily I can change it to wrap std::vector instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is "Maybe", which means you should not bet on this.  Best way would be to play around on your IDE debugger looking up memory addresses.  You'll find this could easily get thrown off when you introduce having members and methods that the compiler can optimize.  For example any constants or a method that doesn't access any members that *could* be static.  Ex:

```
void Object::doSomething() {std::cout << "something\n" << std::endl;}
```

I believe this actually gets optimized into the static allocation because I recently learned that this `((Object)NULL).doSomething();` actually works without a SEGFAULT until you introduce a member variable for `Object`.

Comment: Interesting - two identical classes with the data array as in my question, one with a print function and one without have the same size.
But the pointer arithmetic still seems to work as expected...

Answer (score 1):

There are many factors that decide the size of an object of a class in C++. These factors are:
- Size of all non-static data members
- Order of data members
- Byte alignment or byte padding
- Size of its immediate base class
- The existence of virtual function(s) (Dynamic polymorphism using virtual functions).
- Compiler being used
- Mode of inheritance (virtual inheritance)

check here: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/size_of_class_object.html

Comment: While it is true that the size of objcts can be determined by quite complex rules, those are quite irrelevant in this special case because the array comtains complete objects (you cannot define an array of incomplete objects), and therefore `sizeof Object` already includes any padding, hidden members or what else.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the layout relative to the object's base address will be constant. This is a requirement for the ABI. Any spacing or padding of objects and arrays is also specified by the ABI.