# Memory layout of vector of POD objects

Tags: c++, memory, vector

Suppose I have a simple C++ class,

```
class Data {

    public: 
         float data[3];         

         void clear() { data[0] = 0.0f; data[1] = 0.0f; data[2] = 0.0f }

}
```

And a vector of Data's,

```
std::vector<Data> v(10);
```

Is it safe to assume that `&v[0].data[0]` points to an array of 30 floats?

Comment: Does it point to 30 contiguous `float`? Yes. Does it point to *an array of* 30 `float`? No. There is a difference. It would be far safer to iterate over each `Data`, and then each `data` within that.

Comment: @Cyber What about padding?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ memory in array of class objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025598/c-memory-in-array-of-class-objects)

Comment: I suppose this question is not really interesting, without understanding what the problem is. Do you want to treat the vector as a flat array an index into it?

Comment: Is it safe? Probably not. But that said, I've written several memory map using programs that rely on behavior like this. Use packing pragmas and compile time sizeof asserts.

Comment: Add a single char to your object and compile for a target architecture with strict alignment rules for floats, and the vector elements will no longer be contiguous (size of vector buffer != size of vector entry * number of entries)   If your question is "can I get away with this" my answer is the compiler will probably let you, but I as a co-worker will hunt you down and make you fix your broken code at 3AM when I run into it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From standard

> **23.3.6.1 Class template vector overview**
>
> The elements of a
>   vector are stored contiguously, meaning that if v is a vector where T is some type other
>   than bool, then it obeys the identity &v[n] == &v[0] + n for all 0 <= n < v.size()

so `&v[0]` indeed points to the beginning of 10 continuous `Data` objects.

but for the layout of `Data` we have

> **9.2.13 Class members**
>
> Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control (Clause 11) are allocated so
>   that later members have higher addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of non-static data
>   members with different access control is unspecified (11). Implementation alignment requirements might
>   cause two adjacent members not to be allocated immediately after each other; **so might requirements for
>   space for managing virtual functions (10.3) and virtual base classes (10.1).**

so we cannot be sure that `sizeof(Data) == 3*sizeof(float)`, therefore general answer should be: it's not save to assume 30 continuous floats.

Comment: That only answers half of the question. They are asking basically if all of the internal arrays are contiguous with each other.